# QGIS - Electrical Power Grid: getting the value from a previous line

Tags: qgis, line, pyqgis-3, linestring

I am working with two layers. One of them is a set of lines supposed to represent the electrical grid of a city. And the other one is a set of points representing the utility poles of the grid.

The line layer has two distinct columns. One of these columns is called 'UNIQUE_ID' and indicates an unique ID that each line has. The other column is called 'SOURCE_ID' and is supposed to indicate the unique ID value from the previous line.

I need to get the 'unique ID' value from the previous line into the 'source ID' of the subsequent line.

[image]

In this picture I labeled the points in red and the unique_id of the lines in white. As you can see the line 'MT_788212' is the one closest to the substation so the value of the 'SOURCE_ID' will simply be 'substation_start'. As for the others lines I need to get the unique id from the previous line and put it in the 'SOURCE_ID' column. For example, the subsequent line unique id is 'MT_387811'. The 'SOURCE_ID' of this line needs to be 'MT_788212' because that is the unique ID from the previous line. The next line 'MT_85711' need to have the 'SOURCE_ID' 'MT_387811' and so forth.

Since there's multiple grids and some of them have hundreds of lines I am struggling to find a way to quickly solve this problem. Hope someone shed some light.

Comment: You can do intersection queries, but that will yield two values in most cases. Which to take? I don't see sufficient information to indicate head /tail.  You would have to create another table that for each set of lines say what is your head pole+source_id. That is you need a base case for your induction. Then you would have enough information to write a function or queries to get what you want in your question.